# Request created with fetch or with new Request() has an undefined body

Tags: javascript, stream, request, fetch

Creating a `new Request()` or `fetch()` creates a `Request` with the `Request.body` undefined.

The docs on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request state that `Request` has a `body`:

Quote: "...body: A simple getter used to expose a `ReadableStream` of the body contents."

```
(new Request('http://example.com/')).body
```

in the chrome/ff console gives a `undefined`.

With a POST example you get the same:

```
(new Request('http://example.com/', {
  method: 'POST', 
  body: new ReadableStream({
    pull: function(controller) {
      console.log('pull called!');
      controller.enqueue('Some data...');
    }
  })
})).body
```

I'm expecting the `body` to be available for use in a `ServiceWorker` to a `Request.body` can be inspected and action taken dependent on the `body`.

I've tried cloning the request. 
I've tested both in `ServiceWorker` content and just regular `window` context. 
Tested both Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 66.0.5 (64-bit) on Mac Mojave.

### Note:

This is a known bug in chromium: 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=969843
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=688906

Comment: you've misunderstood the documentation that you linked in your question. [This reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) provides a better view of the Request Constructor. You will see there that you must provide the second argument to the constructor (init object) to actually place anything on the body of the request.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks that's a typo. It doesn't effect the properties of the `Request` object. It does not have a defined getter for `body`. You can also see this in `Request.prototype.body` which is `undefined`.

Comment: This [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/zedupusite/edit?js,console) says otherwise.

Comment: It's showing `undefined`

Comment: I can confirm on MacOS 10.14 Safari works as expected, Chrome 76 does not recognize body and FF 67 does not recognize body. Set Web Platform Experiments flag and Experimental JavaScript flag on Chrome and still does not recognize body. (my answer served its purpose).

Comment: I would have liked to mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll undelete it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: UPDATE TO THIS ANSWER after two+ years of evolution.

Here is a POST Request object constructed with a body. That outputs a ReadableStream object to the console. Note the `.text()` method retrieves a Promise that will resolve to the Request body.

```js
var init = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: "test=testBody"
};

var req = new Request('https://randycasburn.com', init);

req.text().then(console.log);
```

Comment: I get an error: 

{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 22
}

Comment: What version of browser are you using? And OS. Can you test with another browser?

Comment: "If this prints "undefined" in the console for you please let me know.", am facing this

Comment: @MohdSamganKhan - Need to know browser and OS please.

Comment: crome on mac 12.4

Comment: @MohdSamganKhan - I have updated the answer to reflect two+ years of evolution. The code snippet in this answer should run fine on your Mac with Chrome (it does on mine)